# First letter in a sentence dosn’t work in javascript (empty variable in string at a first place)

Tags: javascript, string, variables, uppercase

I use this (I guess typical) function to make a first letter in a sentece capital:

```
function firstLetteCap(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1) }
```

Works perfect till there is an empty variable:

```
// This works perfect
first = "just"
sentence = `${first} a string`
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = `${firstLetteCap(sentence)}.`

// With an empty variable it doesn’t work (capitalized "a" expected)
first = ""
sentence = `${first} a string`
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = `${firstLetteCap(sentence)}.`
```

I would like to know how to fix that, but maybe some context would be also perfect (maybe I don’t get something on how the strings works with variables).

Expected: `Just a string.`

Thanks!

CodePen: https://codepen.io/vojtacejnek/pen/eYybRqg

Comment: Because the rest of the sentence starts with a space. So you capitalize the space. You may want to add `trimStart` somewhere.

Comment: So is your expected result for your second sentence `" A string"` (with the leading space?), or do you want it to be `"A string"` (without the leading space)?

Comment: @NickParsons This was actualy the problem, i was a bit confused with different between space and something like a "no character" or "empty string".

Comment: @Eldar Yes, `trimStart` works good, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, first letter of the `sentence` variable is   (space).

```js
first = ""
sentence = `${first} a string`
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = `${firstLetteCap(sentence)}.`
```

If you want to ignore the extra spaces, you can use `.trim()`.

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_trim.asp